# Given a $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathcal{G}$, does there exist $X$ such that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal{G}$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Does there exist a random variable $X$ such that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal{G}$, and if so, is there a simple way to construct such an $X$?

I am asking this question because I find the definition of conditional expectation much more intuitive when the conditioning is on a random variable, because then we can just think of the conditional expectation $E[Y|X]$ as the function of $X$ that minimizes the expected mean square error.

Comment: Note that while $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]$ makes sense for every $Y \in L^1$, your characterization only makes sense for $Y \in L^2$, so even if you were able to construct such an $X$, your characterization would not make sense for $Y \in L^1 \setminus L^2$.  This isn't to say it's not a useful characterization; just that it cannot be a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO. $\sigma (X)$ is generated by the countable family of  sets $\{X^{-1}(a,b): a,b \in \mathbb Q, a<b\}$. Not every $\sigma$  algebra is countably generated. For example if you take $X=\mathbb R, \mathcal F=\mathcal G=\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ then no such r.v.  $X$ exists.

Comment: Who said that the OP assumed Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain?

Comment: Thanks for the response. What if we set $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{R})$?

Comment: @user253846 There are sub-$\sigma-$ algebras of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ which are not countably generated.